# Where can I find sample automata and turing machines?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, jflap

I'm studying for an automata test on a course that's heavily based on jflap. Trouble is we don't have much documentation and the sample automata that I've found on jlap like [this](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/pda/construct/index.html) and [this](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/jflap/TM/), are insufficient to prepare for the upcoming test.

Where can I find more? Any other resource with sample turing machines shown as graphs with transitions would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Problem solving in automata, languages and complexity" is a fantastic textbook for anything related to... anything in its title. Among other things, you can find a bunch of examples of DFAs/NFAs/PDAs/TMs for all sorts of things, and they teach you a lot of techniques for building them.

Edit: that first link of yours keeps talking about "nondeterministic NPDAs" and "deterministic NPDAs". I'm writing this edit just to satisfy my urge to denounce such pleonasms and oxymora :)

Comment: that book has awesome exapmples. many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try Michael Sipser's excellent book ["Introduction to the Theory of Computation"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Theory-Computation-Michael-Sipser/dp/053494728X/).  The automata and Turing machines are all expressed as state diagrams, with sufficient text explanation to help you interpret and implement them.

This was our course text at Uni about 4 years ago, just before the 2nd edition came out; it was a real rock, I heartily recommend it!